# How to support full text search using entity framwork and UnitOfWork and Repository pattern

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, full-text-search

We are using entity framework 6, UnitOfWork and Repository pattern. We have huge table which requires full text support from SQL. So, there is any simple way which allows us to query the database using linq and entity framework?

For example to search list of products:

```
var itemInformation = UnitOfWork.ProductGs1Repository.RunFullTextContainsQuery(x => x.ItemDescription, searchKeyWords);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to extend your repository `Repository<TEntity>` and add the code below so you can search your entities easily using linq

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> RunFullTextContainsQuery(Expression <Func <TEntity, object>> property, string search)
        {
            if ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search))
            {
                return Enumerable.Empty<TEntity>();
            }

            var unaryExpression = property.Body as UnaryExpression;

            var memberExpression = property.Body as MemberExpression ?? (unaryExpression != null ? unaryExpression.Operand as MemberExpression : null );

            if (memberExpression == null)
            {
                throw new Exception( string.Format( "Invalid lambda expression: '{0}'.", property));
            }

            var query = string.Format( "SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE CONTAINS( {1}, @search)", GetTableName(), memberExpression.Member.Name);

            return _context.Database.SqlQuery<TEntity>(query, new SqlParameter("@search" , search));
        }

        private string GetTableName()
        {
            var objectContext = (( IObjectContextAdapter) _context).ObjectContext;
            var sql = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>().ToTraceString();
            var regex = new Regex( @"FROM\s+(?<table>.+)\s+AS" );
            var match = regex.Match(sql);

            return match.Groups[ "table"].Value;
        }
```

Comment: Right idea (would have had an up vote), but very bad implementation: 1. parametrise your queries, *never* use string concatenation or formatting to build the queries; 2. never use `select *`: a small db change will break your queries.

Comment: Yes you are right. It is good to parametrise the query which already done in the answer but the idea of the answer and question is to show how to use linq to support full text search. So, you can extend with any improvements as you like.

Comment: SQL Injection continues to be a common form of vulnerability, too many "programmers" cut and paste from examples and don't fix them. Therefore my policy is that non-parametrised queries are never acceptable, even in the simplest of examples. The next break in might be your personal data.

Comment: Also, can you explain how search * will break the database for any small changes in the case of querying full text search ?

Comment: OK, an addition or removal of a column from the query will change the result set. In this simple case not too bad (only a single table), but in complex joins it can be hard to identify the problem when the conversion of columns to properties fails. With explicit columns you avoid bring extra data over while making the error much easier to understand.

Comment: You are right in case if you used it in general queries but we are speaking here about "SQL Full Text search" which not supported by entity framework 6

Comment: @SamuelGerges I wrote a bit about it over on P.SE: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/234678/40980 - `select *` is bad for many reasons.

Comment: Appologies: it is parametrised with respect to the search parameter (that use of String.Format enabling the table name to be worked out threw me). I'll make a trivial edit to allow me to remove the down vote (`select *` is poor, SQL injection is unacceptable).